# Redirect to a CDN

Tags: domain, redirect, cdn

I will like to distribute a javascript file with several of my clients, they have several thousands of unique visits a day on their pages, so my file will be called a lot of times, i don't want that pressure on my web server, so i bought a CDN storage from RackSpace.

Since here everything is ok, but the URL of the file, my CDN gives me a very long URL i will like to shorten to something like js-api.mysite.com, so my clients can add that URL to their sites.

I'm not very clear about 2 things:

1. What type of redirect should i use in order to maintain my web server completely out? (i can buy anther domain if necessary)
2. My original long URL is serve in https, do I need to consider that on the selection of the type of redirect?

Comment: A `CNAME` record for what you want the short URL to be would suffice.

Comment: @NathanC Assuming the CDN provider allows it.

Comment: @ceejayoz http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-can-i-use-cnames-with-a-cloud-files-container ...:)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't serve HTTPS though...

Comment: @NathanC Neat. I've got more experience with AWS CloudFront, which requires some configuration on the CDN end to CNAME something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong - source from the CDN directly.

You don't have to go any further than the page source of *this* page:

```
    <meta name="og:image" content="http://cdn.sstatic.net/serverfault/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=9b1f48ae296b"/>
    <meta name="og:title" content="Redirect to a CDN" />
    <meta name="og:description" content="I will like to distribute a javascript file with several of my clients, they have several thousands of unique visits a day on their pages, so my file will be called a lot of times, i don&#39;t want that " />
    <meta name="og:url" content="http://serverfault.com/questions/609568/redirect-to-a-cdn"/>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://serverfault.com/questions/609568/redirect-to-a-cdn" />



    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=d142d951ee55"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/serverfault/all.css?v=01ae6db1af10">
```

Comment: Rackspace doesn't support CNAMEs with https and their cloud "buckets" have annoyingly long hostnames